# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator

I have a strange error trying to launch a test with Appium and UiAutomator2.
The complete error that the terminal throws is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.test.testing' application. Consider checking the driver's troubleshooting documentation. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000' exited with code 1'; Command output: Error: Intent matches multiple activities; can't stop: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 }
```

The capabilities I'm using are:

```
UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
            options.setDeviceName("Pixel 7 Pro API 34");
            options.setAppPackage("com.test.testing");
```

I have confirmed several times the name of the application package, which is mobile application and it is installed correctly.

If anyone can give me a clue as to the source of the error, I'd be very grateful.

It is an automated test on a mobile application